# How was this video made

Tags: video, format, video-encoding, editing, discord

ok guys I'm genuinely confused how this video was made and was wondering whether anyone could shed light on how this video might have been made or encoded or something.

this video in discord is 51 years long in minutes, is 6mb total and 3 hours long in the regular media player but is registered as like 3 seconds long.
[photo of the vid in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZjuD.png)

here's the video:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/837709186997551204/837713898517037096/video0-5-1.mp4

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the file with `mediainfo --fullscan video0-5-1.mp4` and looked at the 'Duration' attributes and yours doesn't match up. Some show '3 min 8 sec' as their value and others have '13:47:50:31'. The multiple 'Duration' attributes should only be different styles of showing you how long your video is and shouldn't differ in value. I guess the creator of the video artificially changed the duration of the video to make it appear longer than it is, but which program was used I unfortunately can't tell you.

It might also just be a corrupted file and no program at all was used.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info